# How to rewrite a JavaScript class with functional programming?

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming

I started with an ES6 Class

```
class Foo {
  id: string;
  bar: string;

  constructor(id: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.bar = 'initial value';
  }

  const someFunctionThatReadsCurrentBarDoesSomethingAndThenChangesBar = () => {
    // Does something based on current bar (which is why this piece of state needs to be memorized
    // then changes bar...
    this.bar = this.bar === 'initial value' ? 'changed initial value' : 'changed value';
  }
}
```

And first changed it according to the [module pattern](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/classes-complexity-and-functional-programming#the-module-pattern)

```
const Foo = (id: string): Foo => {
  let bar: string = 'initial value';

  const someFunctionThatReadsCurrentBarDoesSomethingAndThenChangesBar = () => {
    // Does something based on current bar (which is why this piece of state needs to be memorized
    // then changes bar...
    bar = bar === 'initial value' ? 'changed initial value' : 'changed value';
  }

  return {
    getState: () => ({ id, bar }),
    someFunctionThatReadsCurrentBarDoesSomethingAndThenChangesBar,
  };
};
```

Still it didn't feel very "functional" so I went a bit further and tried to make use of a pure data object, pure functions and a factory function, `makeFoo` as suggested in [this article](https://realworldjs.medium.com/a-javascript-pattern-progression-from-oop-to-functional-style-fp-79b5717e9345).

```
type FooState = { id: string; bar: string };

type Foo = { getState: () => FooState; someFunctionThatReadsCurrentBarDoesSomethingAndThenChangesBar: (state: FooState) => FooState };

const foo = (id: string): FooState => ({
  id,
  bar: 'initial value',
});

const someFunctionThatReadsCurrentBarDoesSomethingAndThenChangesBar = (state: FooState): FooState => ({ ...state, bar: state.bar === 'initial value' ? 'changed initial value' : 'changed value' });

const makeFoo = (id: string): Foo => {
  let state = foo(id); // Question 1: How can I avoid having to reassign state from someFunctionThatReadsCurrentBarDoesSomethingAndThenChangesBar?

  return {
    getState: () => state,
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-return-assign
    someFunctionThatReadsCurrentBarDoesSomethingAndThenChangesBar: () => (state = someFunctionThatReadsCurrentBarDoesSomethingAndThenChangesBar(state)),
  };
};

// USAGE:

// Question 2: How can I avoid having to reassign fooMap from createFoo?
let fooMap: ReadonlyMap<string, Foo> = new Map();

const createFoo = (id: string): Foo => {
  let fooObj = fooMap.get(id);

  if (!fooObj) {
    fooObj= makeFoo(id);

    fooMap = new Map([...fooMap, [id, fooObj]]);
  }

  return fooObj;
};

const foo1 = createFoo("foo1");

// some other part of the code will use foo1 and expect it to have the function someFunctionThatReadsCurrentBarDoesSomethingAndThenChangesBar and invoke it.
```

The problem is that the factory function still holds state, and that I have to reassign the state from the `someFunctionThatReadsCurrentBarDoesSomethingAndThenChangesBar` function. And that does not seem very clean. Ideally var/let should never be necessary in FP if the code is pure.

So I was wondering what it would take to make the following code truly functional? I guess I need to get rid of reassigning let variables, but this is where I'm lost and need some help.

Comment: Please consider Flux architecture (actions, reducers etc ...)

Comment: If `foo(id)` is pure, then `let state = foo(id); /* ... */ getState: () => state,` is equivalent to just inlining it `getState: () => foo(id)`. If you're worried that `foo(id)` will have to perform the operation to return a result every time, you can memoize it - an optimisation easily applied to pure functions.

Comment: `foo(id)` is just the data. I don't understand what you're proposing

Comment: You asked how to avoid declaring the variable. Well, if `foo(id)` is a pure function, you don't need an extra variable, you can inline it.

Comment: Does `someFunctionThatReadsCurrentBarDoesSomethingAndThenChangesBar` have to be a method? Can you just make it a separate function instead?

Comment: But I use the state inside the `someFunctionThatReadsCurrentBarDoesSomethingAndThenChangesBar` - both reads the current value and sets it to a new value based on what the old was. Without assigning it to a variable `state` how would that work? Then the state change would always be reset when you call `foo(id)` again and again.

Comment: @LambdaFairy can you elaborate? If you mean if the `someFunctionThatReadsCurrentBarDoesSomethingAndThenChangesBar` function needs to be returned as part of the object, yes it needs to. The consuming code depends on that the object has those "properties"

Comment: Can you please post your actual code? It's very hard to advise a solution if we don't know what purpose `someFunctionThatReadsCurrentBarDoesSomethingAndThenChangesBar` has.

Comment: @Bergi I did just update the code and that function in particular. It simply needs to be able to read the current state (in this case, the current value of foo to keep it as simple as possible) and then depending on that state it conditionally sets foo based on that. This is why I did `let state = foo(id)` inside the factory function `makeFoo`

Comment: @Dac0d3r Why are you using strings there, not a boolean? You don't need strings if you just want to toggle it. What does that state *actually* represent? If this is just a toy example, you will only get a toy answer.

Comment: @Bergi it's and example, and I did really try my best to make it. I cannot share company code, but I don't think the important part here is whether it's called foo and what type it is. And no it's not just a toy example - it's as close as I can come within a reasonable amount of time, and without too many unnecessary lines of code that would make it more complicated - without sharing the real code, which I'm not allowed to. It's not because I'm being lazy here... sorry if you feel that way.

Comment: It sounds like a bit like you should be using the state monad but as Bergi says, it's very hard to advise *how*. We don't need your proprietary code but something less idealised than the current example. I personally find it hard to follow because I am not sure what the correct intent is.

Comment: @Dac0d3r Since you never *use* the method in your example, the simplest advise to make the program more functional while still having the same result (creating the same output) would be to omit the method. But that's not what you want. So, again, what do you need the method for?

Comment: @Bergi ........ please, if you're not even going to try and help, please just stop commenting then... As I previously mentioned the function needs to be there on the object, since another part of the code will  expect it and call it. That should be enough info.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm simply trying to rewrite the class with functional programming as pure as possible. It has state, the state is read and evaluated to change the state. That is the challenge. It's just rewriting the class to FP as pure as possible.

Comment: @Dac0d3r There is no generic solution to your challenge. You cannot have a stateful object in pure FP. There are various ways to approximate/describe/emulate state, but we cannot tell you which of them is appropriate for your case if you cannot give more details.

Comment: "*That should be enough info.*" - no, it's not. How does that other code call it? What does it return? Does the other code expect the method call to mutate the instance state? If you want to make this more pure, you will need to also rewrite that other code, and you will need to post it if you want us to answer your question.

Comment: @Bergi the info you need is there. I've shown you the ES6 class I'm trying to migrate to FP and  also that the object needs to have that `someFunctionThatReadsCurrentBarDoesSomethingAndThenChangesBar` method on it since some 3rd party package code will expect an object to have that "property" as it will call that function (like any function call). I cannot rewrite the consuming code as it is a 3rd party package - what I can try to do is keep the code functional in my end by trying to not use a class and I know how the return value object should look like. That should be enough info...

Comment: It is impossible to make a method that mutates the instance state more functional without changing the interface. "*How to rewrite it*" - you can't. (This has nothing to do with using `class` syntax or not, btw).

Comment: @Dac0d3r your approach doesn't really mesh well with FP. The goal is just not inherently compatible. The FP approach would be to not have state or mutations. It's not just not using variables. The latter is largely result of the former but not the end goal. In the spirit of FP you wouldn't have objects that hold anything like state - just functions that consume and transform data. FP will describe that transformation and allow you to re-compose it easier and re-use parts of it elsewhere. Having state for the duration of a computation is doable. There are few approaches like interweaving it

Comment: @Dac0d3r with your results, which generally means making functions that return `[result, state]` and then later functions consume such a tuple and provide a new one. Abstracting away you can make something like `lift = f => x => state => [f(x), state]` to transform a function to produce a state and few generic ones to pass around a state to non-stateful functions. Abstracting further you get the State monad that ferries a state throughout executions. However, your data and state is always supposed to be separate. Having a stateful class that is also FP is not generally compatible.

Comment: @VLAZ I really appreciate all your help, but unfortunately it's too abstract for me to know how to use in practice. Didn't expect it to be this complicated :/

Comment: @Dac0d3r Bergi/VLAZ are right with their comments. However, I think the underlying problem is that you want to convert between two paradigms. Consider a quite idiomatic sentence in a natural language. If you try to translate it word by word you are doomed.from the outset. All you can do is expressing a sentence in the target language that is remotely  similar in its semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a specific "right FP way" to do this. It's about incorporating various techniques that serve your purpose. Here, I'll use the `fp-ts` library to
show you the concepts of

1. the IO monad (to model a synchronous effect, bc your function is called "....DoesSomething...", so we imagine it's writing a Foo to disk)
2. functional composition (using `flow` here, which turns a bunch of functions into a single function)
3. immutability (immutable data reduces the possible errors you can encounter by ensuring the data is always as you expect)
4. lenses, in the category of optics, which deal with focusing on a single prop in an object and are basically a pair of getter and (immutable) setter functions

```js
import * as IO from 'fp-ts/es6/IO'
import { flow } from 'fp-ts/es6/function'
import { Lens } from 'monocle-ts'

// Just for fun, model writing a Foo to disk
declare const writeFooToDisk: (foo:Foo) => IO.IO<Foo>
interface Foo {
  id: string
  bar: string
}

// How to instantiate a Foo
const makeFoo = (id:string):Foo => ({id, bar: 'initial value'})

/* 
 * How to update bar within a Foo; FP prefers immutable data structures.
 * Here, setBar('new val')(oldFoo) does not change oldFoo but returns a new Foo
 */
const setBar = (bar:string) => (foo:Foo):Foo => ({...foo, bar})

/*
 * Here's how you might change your someFunction... (sFTR) to be functional.
 * I assume "does something" means there's a side effect (HTTP fetch, DB read, 
 * disk write). With a side effect, you want to wrap it in an IO (if sync) or
 * Task (if async). For simplicity, I'm assuming the function can never produce
 * an error.
 */
const sFTR: (foo:Foo) => IO.IO<Foo> = flow(
  IO.of,
  IO.chain(writeFooToDisk),
  IO.map(foo => setBar(foo.bar==='initial value'?'initial value changed':'value changed')(foo))
)

///// We can improve this with lenses, another thing in FP:

/*
 * A lens is essentially two functions: a getter and an immutable setter
 * assume type S { A: unknown }, then
 *
 * sLens.get is (s:S) => A, you pass state and it gives you property
 *
 * sLens.set is (a:A) => (s:S) => S, you pass new property, then state, and it
 * gives up updated state
 *
 * some libs provide `modify`, which is like `set` but it takes a function
 * rather than a value, and it modifies the property based on its current value
 */
const barLens = Lens.fromProp<Foo>()('bar')

// This is what we'll pass `modify`
const updateBar = (bar:string) => bar==='initial value' 
  ? 'initial value changed' 
  : 'value changed'

/*
 * We define a function "flow" that lifts a Foo into IO, then writes to disk,
 * then modifies bar, and returns the updated Foo (still wrapped in IO)
 */
const sFTRWithLens: (foo:Foo) => IO.IO<Foo> = flow(
  IO.of,
  IO.chain(writeFooToDisk),
  IO.map(barLens.modify(updateBar))
)

// type IO<A> is just ()=>A, so we can unwrap the Foo like so:
const foo = makeFoo('howdy')
const newFooIO = sFTRWithLens(foo) // IO<Foo>
newFooIO() // Foo

// Or, using flow again. This creates a Foo, writes it to disk, updates bar,
// and returns the updated Foo
flow(makeFoo, newFooIO, newFooIO)('howdy') // { id: 'howdy', bar: 'updated initial value' }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this amazing answer. This will seriously make all the difference for me to get started with FP. Reading documentation / articles hasn't been enough for me so far, since it's a completely new way of thinking and writing code, but seeing how a class with attributes and a method that mutates its class attributes can be translated to FP like this is insanely helpful and I believe a lot of other JS developers coming from an OOP background will benefit from this answer as well. So thank you for taking the time to do this, instead of pointing how stupid / lackingmy question is.

Comment: You are correct in your assumptions. The id is a "moduleId", and there's a 2nd param, which is () => import("./module"). Instead of "bar" there're "error", "promise" and "result" (all initialized to null) which are all mutated from inside the "someFunctionThatReadsCurrentBarDoesSomethingAndThenChangesBar" function which is called "loadModule". The logic inside is that if promise is not null (first run) you return it. Otherwise you set promise equal to the () => import("./someModule") param. You also set the result equal to the awaited promise and if there's an error you set that and throw it.

Comment: So if promise (in state) is not null, return the promise. Else (only first time the loadModule func runs), set the promise state (so it's not null next time), await the promise, set the result state and return the result - if an error occurs, set the error state and throw an error.
Due to the additional challenges of understanding async concepts in FP, I deliberately left this out and "dumbed" it down to a function that mutates state. To keep things separate.